# How to display data from two models in one table based on common attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have two different models:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public int      Id         { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date       { get; set; }
    public string   Attribute1 { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public int      Id         { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date       { get; set; }
    public string   Attribute2 { get; set; }
    public string   Attribute3 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to display this in a single view in the same table. The models are mostly unrelated. I would like to ignore the Ids in the table, but display items ordered by date in such a way:

```
| Date       | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 |
| 2008-01-01 | null       | value      | value      | (ModelB item)
| 2009-01-01 | value      | null       | null       | (ModelA item)
| 2010-01-01 | value      | null       | null       | (ModelA item)
| 2011-01-01 | null       | value      | value      | (ModelB item)
```

For clarity: I do not wish to show the difference other than by having empty spots in the table where there is no data for one of the cells.

Joining the data sets does not work as there are no values that I want to join on (I want all dates to display), it's more the column that I want to join on.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but is it equivalent to the SQL's `UNION` operation?

Comment: It was indeed a union operator, with the required additional step of creating new objects to be able to do so, as shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can union them, something like this you should do

```
list1.Select(x => new {
                           Id         = x.Id, 
                           Date       = x.Date, 
                           Attribute1 = x.Attribute1, 
                           Attribute2 = null, 
                           Attribute3 = null
                        }
             ).Union(list2.Select(x => new {
                           Id         = x.Id, 
                           Date       = x.Date, 
                           Attribute1 = null, 
                           Attribute2 = x.Attribute2, 
                           Attribute3 = x.Attribute3
                     }));
```

and do your operation over the union list

Comment: I ended up creating a new class to capture this otherwise nameless object and used that in my view. Worked perfectly!